# Update multiple(not all) rows with different set of values - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table - pms_samplebucket:

```
partid | qty | inqty
--------------------
 4     | 5   | 3
 5     | 10  | 5
 6     | 10  | 5
 7     | 10  | 5 ----- n rows
```

I would like to update this table as follows:

- IF partid = '4' THEN inqty = inqty - 2;
- IF partid = '5' THEN inqty = inqty - 4;

Is it possible to do this in a single UPDATE or INSERT INTO .... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement?

1. I dont want multiple queries.
2. The partid values and subtraction values will be provided as input.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes:

```
update t
    set inqty = (case when partid = 4 then inqty - 2
                      when partid = 5 then inqty - 4
                      else inqty
                 end)
    where partid in (4, 5);
```

Comment: Thank you. This is fine for a small set - what if the number of affected rows is more?

Comment: @ParndhamanM . . . I see no issue.  This updates exactly the number of rows that need to be updated.

Comment: Gordon the number of rows vary, I will be creating this query on the fly. Is there a  shorter version?

Comment: Thank you very much Gordon - for now this will suffice. In the near future the number of rows may not exceed 10. Appreciate you response and effort.